# Execute a complex command on every folder of your Filesystem

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to execute often the following command which compresses all the PNG files in a folder:

```
for %i in (*.png) do pngout.exe "%i" /kp
```

So I have added this command in a file png.cmd and added the folder to the system PATH.

However when I execute the command (png.cmd) from a point in my file system, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Desktop>png  
i" /kp was unexpected at this time.
```

Is there a way to fix this problem, also I'm thinking where the shell is going to execute the png.cmd command ? In the path where I've created the png.cmd file ? I'd need to execute it in the current PATH where I'm with the shell. 
Any idea?
Thanks a alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax error is caused by using only 1 `%` in your `for` loop variable, when you use a batch file you need to use 2 to escape the first one.

```
for %%i in (*.png) do pngout.exe "%%i" /kp
```

With regards to your path question, fix this first, then see if it's still an issue.